# Getting a return Value from a different file into a variable

Tags: php

So I have 2 files. File A and File B.

File A is a php config file, it's just an array with a bunch of values.. as seen below.

```
<?php

return array(
'name' => 'A bunch of cats',
'look' => 'stunning',
'description' => 'Cat\'s doing stupid stuff');
```

That's litterally it, nothing else is in that config file.

Now in file B, how would I get that array? I can't really use an include in this case because I am unable to reference the return value in any way. Changing the config to be a variable is not an option since it is a dependency of many other scripts.

Comment: what do you mean unable to reference the return value? you can use that `return` and assign it into a variable, ala `$whatever = include 'path/to/file_a.php';`

Comment: I can? I did not know you could simply assign an include to a variable. It makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: yes you can, just do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0 :p

Comment: Don't forget to escape the apostrophe in `Cat's`

Comment: this for one thing `'Cat's doing stupid stuff'` will generate a parse error.

Comment: @Ghost Haha cheers mate. Thankyou every one else for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I assigned the include to a variable. Easy solution.

Cheers

Comment: You mean [*"Ghost found it..."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190322/getting-a-return-value-from-a-different-file-into-a-variable#comment58097850_35190322)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and call it using `example()` for it to return the data without a variable.

```
    function example() {
        return array(
            'name' => 'A bunch of cats',
            'look' => 'stunning',
            'description' => 'Cat's doing stupid stuff');
    }
```

Comment: `'Cat's doing stupid stuff'` will fail. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to show my real code so I made a small example. I missed that I guess.

Comment: @derpyderp in doing that, you risk this guy getting downvoted for it. It's either `'Cat\'s doing stupid stuff'` or `"Cat's doing stupid stuff"`